# Exception at math.round function

Tags: java, exception, math, rounding

I got an exception at exactly this line and can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
SecondsText.setText(Math.round(SecondsTime));
```

This the rest of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    long AnDate = 1476650909;
    TextView SecondsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SecondsText);
    TextView MinutesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MinutesText);
    TextView HoursText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HoursText);
    TextView DaysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DaysText);
    long SecondsTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - AnDate;
    long MinutesTime = SecondsTime/60;
    long HoursTime = MinutesTime/60;
    long DaysTime = HoursTime/24;
    **SecondsText.setText(Math.round(SecondsTime));**
    MinutesText.setText(Math.round(MinutesTime));
    HoursText.setText(Math.round(HoursTime));
    DaysText.setText(Math.round(DaysTime));
}
```

And the exception says

```
> 10-12 15:32:25.920 9254-9254/com.example.mauro.howmuchtime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mauro.howmuchtime, PID: 9254
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mauro.howmuchtime/com.example.mauro.howmuchtime.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3bd011c
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3bd011c
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5496)
    **at com.example.mauro.howmuchtime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

java.lang.Math is imported, SecondsText is a textview object in Android Studio and SecondsTime is a long variable, and I'm looking to remove the decimals out of it. I know it is a really stupid question but can't really figure it out, I'm new to Java. Thanks!

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Please include the details of the exception in your question: The exception message, and the stack trace.  You should also include all relevant code, not just this line.  Also, you don't need to import `Math`, or anything else in the `java.lang` package.

Comment: is `SecondsTime` really a long (is it a float or double) and a decimal?

Comment: `round(long)` does not exist in `Math`

Comment: @PM77-1 A `long` would get promoted to `float` to be passed to `Math.round`.

Comment: I added more context. I apologise for doing such a stupid question, but I'm new :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SecondsTime` is a `float`, which will call the overloaded version of [`round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) which returns an `int`. The [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) method that accepts an int defines the parameter as:

> the resource identifier of the string resource to be displayed.

Since the `int` that you are passing is not a resource identifier, you'll need to convert it to a `String` to call the `setText(CharSequence text)` version. You can do this with the `String.valueOf()` method:

```
SecondsText.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(SecondsTime)));
```

Comment: You're actually wrong. The code `SecondsText.setText(Math.round(SecondsTime));` wouldn't compile if you were right, but if `SecondsTime` is a `float`, not a `double` like you're assuming, then [`round(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) returns an `int`, and there is a [`setText(int resid)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)), which also explains the exception message *"Resources$NotFoundException: String **resource ID** #0x3bd011c"*.